# How do you access a variable in sveltekit set in an imported compontent?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I know how to use props in sveltekit but how do you get a variable "height" the other way set in Nested.svelte at the same time?

```
//App.svelte
<script>
    import Nested from './Nested.svelte';
</script>
{height}
<Nested answer={42}/>

//Nested.svelte
<script>
    export let answer;
    export let height;
</script>

<div bind:clientHeight={height}>The answer is {answer}</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare a local variable use `bind` on the component:

```html
<script>
    import Nested from './Nested.svelte';
    let height;
</script>
<Nested bind:height />
```

Or without shorthand if the variable name is different:

```html
<script>
    import Nested from './Nested.svelte';
    let nestedHeight;
</script>
<Nested bind:height={nestedHeight} />
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/2f53e4f318074e5c942eaee885ce6ec3?version=3.47.0)